# Los constructores no me dejan cargar los métodos por consola en Java

Tags: java, poo, constructor, parametros

En esta ocasión estoy realizando los retoques finales a un menú de opciones que usa métodos para agregar autos y motos y otro que calcula el coste de sus reparaciones

Mi problema es que los constructores poseen parámetros
y al querer usarlos para darle datos por entrada de consola da error porque no puedo usar los objetos sin dichos parámetros

Les adjunto los fragmentos del código para que lo revisen desde ya agradezco su atención

1)_Objetos con parámetros para poder usarlos

```
//Declaracion de objetos   
automovil auto = new automovil("Audi","A8","ABC123","Lujo",5);
    moto motocicleta = new moto("Kawasaki","Taka Taka","CBA 456",450);
    Logica ruedas = new Logica("Neumaticos",50,3,130,1);    
    Logica luces = new Logica("Luces Delanteras y faros traseros",30,4,260,2);
    Logica aboyaduras = new Logica("Chapa y Pintura Color gris y relleno de Fibra de vidrio",20,6,520,4);
```

2)_ EL constructor correspondiente a los objetos de logica

```
Contructor
        public Logica(String repuesto,int valorR,int cantR,int costosest,int diasEmp){
            
            this.repuesto = repuesto;
            this.valorR = valorR;
            this.diasEmp = diasEmp;
            this.costosest = costosest;
            this.cantR = cantR;
```

3)_Enunciado del menu solicitando los valores

```
System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del respuesto: \n");
                    String repuesto = entrada.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el precio del respuesto: \n");
                    int pieza = entrada.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese las unidades a usar: \n");
                    int unidades = entrada.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese los dias a emplear: \n");
                    int dias = entrada.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el precio por estadia: \n");
                    int estadia = entrada.nextInt();
                    
                    System.out.println("El coste de la reparacion es: $"+luces.totalReparacion());
                }
```

Pd: Para aclarar puse los parámetros en los objetos para tratar de ver el funcionamiento del código pero si los quito simplemente no compila porque no se puede dejar sin parámetros

y mi objetivo es poder pedirle al usuario datos y almacenarlos en las variables para poder calcular y cargar datos

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Si lo que quieres es usar los objetos sin parámetros entonces declara a las respectivas clases un constructor sin parámetros. OJO: en Java puedes tener **múltiples constructores**, de modo que puedes tener uno sin paŕametros y otro(s) con parámetros.

Comment: ósea mi problema es quiero cargar datos por consola ósea quiero que el usuario los cargue pero a la hora de instanciar el objeto para usar el método que le pediría al usuario cargar dichos datos me da error porque tengo un constructor con parámetros definidos que tuve que heredar anteriormente y yo no quiero rellenar esos parámetros sino que el usuario los complete y no tengo idea de como hacer eso

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras: 1. Recoges primero los datos que serían los parámetros del constructor de la clase, los guardas en variables y cuando los tengas todos creas la instancia de la clase usando esas variables como parámetros para el constructor; 2. Declaras en las clases un constructor vacío, creas una instancia de la clase usando ese constructor y luego vas recogiendo cada campo de la clase y pasándolo a la instancia creada mediante los *setter*.